# Is hold that $(x_{n_k})$ converge then $(x_{n_k})$ is bounded. So $(x_n)$ is bounded.?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence monotone.

Assume that $(x_{n_k})\subseteq (x_n)$ is a subsequence such that $x_{n_k}$ converge to $x$ .

Then $(x_n)$ is converge to $x$.

Is hold that $(x_{n_k})$ converge then $(x_{n_k})$ is bounded. So $(x_n)$ is bounded.?

Any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $(x_n)$ is bounded since it converges.  Suppose $x_n$ is an increasing sequence. You can write $n_k=\phi(k)$ where $\phi$ is an increasing function. $(x_{n_k})$ is increasing and converges so it is bounded. There exists $M$ such that $x_{n_k}<M$. For every $l$, $\phi(l)>l$ thus since is increasing, $x_l\leq x_{n_l}\leq M$. Obviously, $x_n\geq x_0$.

If $(x_n)$ decreases, consider $(-x_n)$ which is an increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a subsequence that converges to x (your hypothesis), then that subsequence is bounded.

So, from the fact that every bounded monotone sequence is convergent then, if a monotone sequence (which is the case) has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, then $(x_n)$ itself is convergent. $(x_n)$ is monotone by our hypothesis, and it is bounded because it has a bounded subsequence (again, because $(x_{n_k})$ converges).

By the statement that $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$, $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ as well. Note that, if it wasn't stated that $(x_n)$ was monotone, that sequence could converge or not - it could have, beyond that convergent subsequence, another convergent subsequence that would converge to a value different from $x$ - in that case, we say the sequence has to adherent values.